# C# WebBrowser.Document.Body.AppendChild is failing to add new element

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

The .NET WebBrowser control does not seem to have a method which allows for inserting html elements from their string into the document body as the `AppendChild` method requires a type `HtmlElement`. In the following code, I am attempting to overcome this as `Document.Body` returns the type `HtmlElement` so I am creating a new WebBrowser control, setting the whole body to the text, and then retrieving the result as `HtmlElement`.

#### Control Code

```
public class WebBrowserEx : WebBrowser {

    // method to allow creation of HtmlElement from HTML text
    public HtmlElement CreateElement(string html)
    {
        HtmlElement el;
        using(WebBrowser wb = new WebBrowser())
        {
            wb.Navigate("about:blank");
            try
            {
                if (wb.Document != null) { wb.Document.Write(string.Empty); }
            } catch (InvalidCastException) { }
            wb.Document.Write(html);
            el = wb.Document.Body;
        }
        return el;
    }

    // method to set entire document from HTML text
    public string Html {
        get {
            return DocumentText;
        }
        set{
            Navigate("about:blank");
            try
            {
                if (Document != null) { Document.Write(string.Empty); }
            } catch (InvalidCastException) { }
            wb.Document.Write(html);
        }
    }
}
```

### Example Use

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        // create a new instance of the WebBrowserEx control
        WebBrowserEx wbex = new WebBrowserEx();

        // set the document to HTML content
        wbex.Html = "<html><head></head><body></body></html>";

        // create a new element from HTML as string
        HtmlElement el = wbex.CreateElement("<h1>Hello World</h1><br>");

        // append new element to document
        wbex.Document.Body.AppendChild(el);
    }
}
```

The problem I am encountering is when I try to append that result using `Document.Body.AppendChild`, it is giving me the following exception:

> Value does not fall within the expected range.

This also gives the same exception when trying to insert the element using

```
wbex.Document.Body.InsertAdjacentElement(HtmlElementInsertionOrientation.AfterEnd, el);
```

### Image of exception

[image: the exception]

### NOTE

I am aware of adding individual elements using `Document.CreateElement("A")` where "A" is the element, however this doesn't allow for adding a block of html which contains many elements. I am also aware of being able to insert JavaScript and have that run on the fly which you can also create elements with. I am also aware that I could just store my HTML in a string, append to that, and then set the document html again, however this would lose any existing state or dynamic changes in the page.

The objective is to be able to simply add a block of html from a string to anywhere in an existing html document that is already loaded in the WebBrowser control directly.